# Is there a way to make an API call from Azure runbook?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-automation, azure-runbook, runbook

I have an automation account in Azure and I have a runbook in it. What I'm trying to do is to make an API call from this runbook. I'll need to login to some web service, get a session token and then use this session token to call some controller's methods.

So far I have only found some ways to call Azure runbooks through API (let's say from some backend c# code), but not vica versa. What I need to do is to call some c# methods **FROM** Azure runbook.

Is there a way to do it? If there is, how do I pass queries within my call?
What I'm expecting to see is something like:

```
$response = MakeApiCall -Url "www.someurl.com" -Body "some json for example"
```

Comment: Powershell runbook? Is [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

It's either

```
$Url = "https://my-url"
$Body = @{
    field = "value"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

or

```
Invoke-WebRequest
```

Invoke-RestMethod by default parses output, Invoke-WebRequest donesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try this one and let you know right away.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work for Azure runbooks. It works locally but when I try it in Azure I get: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. They do not work for localhost but they do for normal urls.